# .htaccess redirect broken links to php page with parameters intact

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php website with a `docs` folder in the root, the structure of the site is thus:

```
sitename.com/docs/
```

In the docs folder are PDF's that sometimes cause browser issues because of spaces in the names, so they are not found (mainly by IE).

What I would like to do is the following:

Whenever there is a broken URL in the `docs/` directory, I would like to redirect the entire query string to a php page within the docs directory, but it must keep the name of the PDF intact.

Thus, is the URL is:

```
website.com/docs/this is a pdf
```

I want it to redirect to:

```
website.com/docs/index.php?pdf=this is a pdf
```

From there, I can grab the PDF `param` and fix it up and send the request to the correct file.

The reason this is not done with straight `.htaccess` is that I cannot find a solution that is dynamic, in other words the number of words in the PDF is variable, and could be from 1 to 20 words, separated by spaces.

I had a post up here about that at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250903/apache-rewrite-urls-with-spaces) which did get one reply, however, it still does not address the variable URL length problem.

I have again tried this from the examples in [this tutorial](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) but this has not helped me at all as I cannot fathom how to do this properly.

The one thing that I think is close is the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^docs/(.*) /index.php?pdf=$1 [NC]
```

Am I close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should know that, only static codes can be written in .htaccess, and we cannot process to a dynamic code,
The Following solution might help for you am not tested
`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteRule ^docs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?pdf=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Have your rule like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^docs/((?=[^\s]*\s).+?)/?$ /docs/index.php?pdf=$1 [NC,L,B,QSA]
```

This will forward all PDFs with spaces to `/docs/index.php` while leaving non space file names intact.